# Suggestions on keycloak integration

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm currently working on a project with **Spring Boot** & **React**, can you please refer to what is the best strategy or way of integrating **Keycloak** as an authentication server in the app.
It's my first time working with **Keycloack** (if you can recommend a good tutorial I will be thankful).

Comment: What are the recommendations that you get ?

Answer (score 0):

We used this guide to host keycloak on aws:
https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/solutions/keycloak-on-aws/

We used a python backend so can't really help you on the Spring boot front.

We used [oidc-react](https://github.com/bjerkio/oidc-react) to communicate with keycloak on the frontend, that builds on [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js)